# How do I reload a container view when navigating backwards using a segue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, splitcontainer

In Xcode I am have two container views implemented in a UIViewController.
I use a modal segue to navigate forward on one view which correctly loads.
My problem is that when I navigate back to the previous page my other container view does not reload automatically.

How do I manually force this container to load when navigating back?

Note: it will correctly load when I navigate forward to this page, however my problem only arrises when navigating backwards.

I have researched quite a few options but can't find a clear example of how to do this.

Comment: You need to explain your setup more clearly. It doesn't make sense to navigate to a container view with a modal segue. When you say container views, do you mean the container views you get in IB that have a view controller embedded in them?

Comment: Are you dismissing the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the reload code in this method

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    // reload stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Think my problem was that I had not put the code in viewWillAppear of the delegate controller.